# Angular2 tsconfig - Exclude file as entry point during build

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I'm working on an Angular2 library project that has an `index.ts` file which is the entry point to the main application, and a `test.ts` which is the entry point for the testing setup (starts Karma, imports test `.ts` files). My `tsconfig.json` file (included below) contains both entry files. This works fine during development and testing however when I run a build the `test.ts` file is also included. If I remove the `test.ts` file from the `files` array Webstorm marks every usage of a decorator in the codebase as being an error (`experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release...`).

Is there a way I can fix this so the IDE uses the `tsconfig.json` file for the test files, but does not include it when building?

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@angular/core": ["node_modules/@angular/core"],
      "@angular/testing": ["node_modules/@angular/testing"],
      "rxjs/*": ["node_modules/rxjs/*"]
    },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015", 
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "index.ts",
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

*Build scripts for reference

```
// package.json

...
"scripts": {
    "cleanup": "rimraf dist/bundles dist/src dist/index.d.ts dist/index.js dist/index.js.map dist/LICENCE dist/README.md",
    "bundling": "rollup -c",
    "minify": "uglifyjs dist/bundles/my-library.umd.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --comments --output dist/bundles/async-local-storage.umd.min.js",
    "copy": "copyfiles LICENSE README.md dist",
    "build": "npm run cleanup && ngc && npm run bundling && npm run minify && npm run copy"
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by creating a second tsconfig file (`tsconfig.build.json`) and updating the `build` script to use that file;

```
"build": "npm run cleanup && ngc -p tsconfig.build.json && npm run bundling && npm run minify && npm run copy"
```